# How i will get Organization URN for linked-In ads

Tags: linkedin-api

I am new in linked-In ads creation and now I am doing "Direct Sponsored Content Share" ad creation for this I need owner(Organization URN).

[Creation link (Direct Sponsored Content Share)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#direct-sponsored-content-share)

But from where i will get owner(Organization URN)